# Не работает флаг смены хода

Tags: c++, qt, ооп, qt5

Есть публичное поле класса — `gamer`, которое служит флагом смены хода.

Изначально оно равно `false`. Это значит, что будут использоваться только слоты, которые рисуют крестики. Как только будет нарисован крестик, поле `gamer` станет равно `true` и будут использоваться слоты, которые рисуют нолик.

Однако что-то идет не так, и `gamer` всегда равно `false`.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <unistd.h>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : 
    QDialog(parent), 
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->sq_one_one->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_one_two->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_one_three->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_two_one->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_two_two->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_two_three->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_three_one->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_three_two->setFixedSize(50,50);
    ui->sq_three_three->setFixedSize(50,50);
    play();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::play() {
    if (gamer == false) {
        connect(ui->sq_one_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_one_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_one_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(krest_drow()));

    } else {
        connect(ui->sq_one_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_one_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_one_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_two_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_two,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
        connect(ui->sq_three_three,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(nol_drow()));
    }
}

void Dialog::krest_drow() {
    this->gamer = true;
    QPushButton* sq_button = (QPushButton*) sender();
    sq_button->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/krestus"));
    sq_button->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));
}

void Dialog::nol_drow() {
    this->gamer = false;
    QPushButton* sq_button = (QPushButton*) sender(); 
    sq_button->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/lus"));
    sq_button->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас какая-то фигня написана. Вы в методе `play` соединяете сигналы от кликов по кнопке с двумя разными слотами в зависимости от значения переменной gamer. То есть в начале `gamer == true` и происходит соединение со слотами для крестика. Потом `gamer` меняется на `false`, но соединение-то уже установлено, и выполняется опять ход крестиков.

Я бы посоветовал что-то такое:

```
connect(ui->sq_one_one,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(turn()));
....

void turn()
{
    QPushButton* button = (QPushButton*) sender();
    if (gamer == true)
       //проставить крестик
    else
       //проставить нолик
    gamer = !gamer;
}
```

З.Ы. Не забудьте проинициализировать переменную `gamer`, а то могут быть забавные сюрпризы